# How to call a function after subscriber complete in angular 8+

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Hello everyone I am learning angular and firebase. So the idea is I fetch some ticket from my ticket collection and after fetching add some new property in it but the problem is when I receive half data my ordering function call (the function which is responsible for adding a property). or in simple word we can say I receive data in stream form.

```
 get_ticket() {
  console.log('have permission');
  this.get_ticket_service
    .get_ticket_company(this.user.company)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('get response');
      this.unStructure_ticket = res.map((e) => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          item: e.payload.doc.data(),
        };
      });
      this.odering_ticket(this.unStructure_ticket)
    });
```

ordering function

```
  odering_ticket(data) {
    const info = [];
    console.log('hi');
    data.map((ticket) => {
      if (ticket.item.seen == false) {
        ticket.item.ticketID = ticket.id;
        ticket.item.ticketType = 'new';
        info.push(ticket.item);
      } else if (
        ticket.item.new == true &&
        ticket.item.currently_handle_sme_ID == undefined
      ) {
        ticket.item.ticketID = ticket.id;
        ticket.item.ticketType = 'not assigned';
        info.push(ticket.item);
      } else if (
        ticket.item.currently_handle_sme_ID == localStorage.getItem('uid') &&
        !this.has_view_all_ticket_permission
      ) {
        ticket.item.ticketID = ticket.id;
        ticket.item.ticketType = 'assigned';
        info.push(ticket.item);
      } else if (
        ticket.item.currently_handle_sme_ID != undefined &&
        this.has_view_all_ticket_permission
      ) {
        ticket.item.ticketID = ticket.id;
        ticket.item.ticketType = 'assigned';
        info.push(ticket.item);
      }
    });
    console.log('end map');
    return info;
  }
```

service.ts

```
  get_ticket_company(company) {
    return this.firebase_store
      .collection('Ticket', (ref) => ref.where('company', '==', company))
      .snapshotChanges();
  }
```

output

have permission ,
get response ,
hi ,
end map ,
get response ,
hi ,
end map,

I want to call my ordering function one's after I receive all data

Comment: You are already calling `odering_ticket` after the observable returned by `get_ticket_company` completes. Does `get_ticket_company` emits multiples times ?

Comment: yeah , ordering function call two times

Answer (score 1):

You must try to use the [last RxJs operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last) which will make your pipeline wait until the last emitted value.

```
 this.get_ticket_service
    .get_ticket_company(this.user.company).pipe(
        tap((poRes) => {
            console.log('get response');
            if (this.unStructure_ticket === undefined) {
                // Initialize your data structure.
                this.unStructure_ticket = res.map((e) => {
                    return {
                        id: e.payload.doc.id,
                        item: e.payload.doc.data(),
                    };
                });
            } else {
                // Add or concate the data received
                // this.unStructure_ticket.push()//;
            }
        }),
        last(), // Wait for the last emitted value.
        tap((poRes) => {
            this.odering_ticket(this.unStructure_ticket);
        }),
    ).subscribe();
```

Example of how this should work, but not tested code.